# Rspec, shoulda and spork does not work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda, spork

when I run `rspec spec/models` result is OK.

But when I use **spork**, every test where shoulda macros (like `it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }` is used FAILS with error like: `undefined method 'validate_presence_of' for ...`

I use:

```
rails (3.0.0)
shoulda (2.11.3)
spork (0.8.4)
rspec-rails (>= 2.0.0.beta.22)
```

spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'shoulda'
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by sticking `require 'shoulda/integrations/rspec2'` after requiring `rspec/rails` in prefork block.

You might also want to upgrade your spork to the latest version (`gem 'spork', >= 0.9.0.rc2`), since I didn't try this fix on 0.8.4 (although I am pretty sure it'll work too)

Comment: For current shoulda-matcher try `require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'`

Comment: You might find some help on this wiki page: https://github.com/timcharper/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujutsu

Comment: For me this worked: require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the

```
require "shoulda"
```

line into the `Spork.each_run` block. Apparently, shoulda does some magic to include the matchers into the appropriate example groups.

Comment: I moved require 'shoulda' into Sprok.prefork and it worked for me.